# Codeigniter transaction not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a function which inserts row into a table, something like below

```
function fn_insert_user() {
    $this->db->trans_begin();
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO user VALUES(9,"john", "9865321245")');
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO user VALUES(8,"martin", "8865321245")');
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        echo 'something bad happened';
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        echo 'everything is fine';
    }

}
```

Now primary key 8 already exists and hence as expected it should not allow to insert second query (which is fine).

It successfully rolls back first query but the problem is that instead of printing 'something bad happened' it prints

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1062
Duplicate entry '8' for key 'PRIMARY'
INSERT INTO user VALUES(8,"martin", "8865321245")
Filename: C:\wamp\www\landmark\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

Comment: already the enrty `8` is inserted.please check your db

Comment: Truncate your table and and try with complete new entry.

Comment: Yes I know that but as it results into error it should have printed error 'something bad happened' and not usual codeigniter error

Answer (score 3):

If you do

```
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

And

```
$this->db->trans_commit();
```

Then it will commit the transaction twice.

You have 2 solutions :

```
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->query('QUERY');
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
        echo "fail";
    }
```

OR

```
$this->db->trans_begin();
$this->db->query('QUERY...');


if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

See documentation for further details ; http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not a transation problem...

Try it:

```
function fn_insert_user() {

    $this->db->trans_begin();
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO user VALUES("john", "9865321245")');
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO user VALUES("martin", "8865321245")');
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        echo 'something bad happened';
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        echo 'everything is fine';
    }

}
```